# How to draw border around other application windows

Tags: winapi, javafx, window, border

I am developing a javafx project, I want to draw border around other application window from my project, I have already used the JNA library for doing so, but could not make progress. Here is the code snippet I am using for drawing border around other application window whose pointer is "hwnd"

```
        private  void highlightWindow(WinDef.HWND hwnd) {
        WinDef.RECT rect = new WinDef.RECT();
        if (User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(hwnd, rect)) {
            int borderSize = 5; // Adjust the border size as needed

            // Draw a border around the window
            drawBorder(hwnd, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, borderSize);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to get window rect.");
        }
    }

    private  void drawBorder(WinDef.HWND hwnd, int x, int y, int width, int height, int borderSize) {
        User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowPos(
                hwnd,
                null,
                x - borderSize, y - borderSize,
                width + 2 * borderSize, height + 2 * borderSize,
                User32.SWP_FRAMECHANGED
        );
    }
```

I was trying to reset the window position to draw a visible border